# WordPress Redirection plugin to include query parameters in target URL

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using the WordPress Redirection plugin to redirect old landing pages to a new domain.

I'm able to match URLs including any query strings and this redirects 100% to the new domain.

Example:
**From:**

```
/page/(\?.+)?$
```

**To:**

```
https://new-site.com/page
```

How can I include query strings in the target URL of the plugin so that the browsers will redirect to something like this:

```
https://new-site.com/page?q=test&s=test2
```

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /usbed/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /usbed/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What are your current directives?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'directive'

Comment: The rules you have in your .htaccess file.

Comment: I've added the contents of the .htaccess

Comment: Are you trying to apply rewrite rules directly in .htaccess file or within Wordpress?

Comment: I'm using redirection plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166679/discussion-between-marcus-christiansen-and-revo).

Comment: Try with `https://new-site.com/page$1`. See https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/ for more details. You can also try this RegEx: `/page(|/|/?\?.+)$`

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ you can place it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: You're welcome. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple, actually.

Just set the *Target URL* to:

```
https://new-site.com/page$1
```

`$1` refers to the contents of the captured `(\?.+)` in the RegEx you provided.

See https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/ for more details.

See sample below:

[image]

However, in that example, I used this RegEx: `/page(|/|/?\?.+)$`, which matches these URLs: (you can test it on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/), but you need to escape the `/` with a `\`; hence you'd use `\/page(|\/|\/?\?.+)$`, which is also accepted by the [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin)

```
http://example.com/page
http://example.com/page/
http://example.com/page?q=test&s=test2
http://example.com/page/?q=test&s=test2
```

Comment: I tested and confirmed this solution is working for Redirection plugin with 4.3.3.

Comment: Thanks for helping in testing it, @V-SHY :)